# ¿Cómo rescatar los inputs que contengan datos y almacenarlos en un array?

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    {!! Form::label('documentos', 'Documentos') !!}
    
    @foreach ($documentos as $documento)
    <div class="checkbox" onchange="javascript:mostrarOcultar()">
        
        <label>
            {!! Form::checkbox('documento[]', $documento->id, null, 
                ['class' => 'field check']) !!}
            {{ $documento->nombre }} 
        </label>
        
        <label> 
            <div >
            {!! Form::text('details[]', null, 
                ['class' => 'form-control detalle',
                'style' => 'display: block;', 
                'placeholder' => 'Detalles',
                'title' => 'OPCIONAL : Ingrese una especificación del documento.'])
            !!}
            </div>
        </label>
        
    </div>

    @endforeach

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function mostrarOcultar() 
            {
                detalle = document.getElementsByName('details');
                check = document.getElementsByClassName('field check');

                detalle.style.display = (check.checked) ? 'block' : 'none';

            } 
        </script>
</div>
```

Se ve de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al querer rescatar los valores del input detalle, este me muestra todos los valores del array y yo solo quiero que me muestre los que tengan datos (relleno):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio los valores de documentos me los guarda en un array pero **sólo** los que han sido seleccionados:

Los valores que se muestran corresponden a las id de los documentos seleccionados.

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es: ¿De qué manera puedo hacer que los "detalles" se guarden de la misma manera que documentos?

> **PD:** los documentos están almacenados en la BD en cambio los detalles son datos nuevos que se deben adjuntar a la BD.

Hay una relación de muchos a muchos en entre documentos y registros y en la tabla intermedia (document_registry) se encuentra el campo "detalle", la idea es que cada detalle esté asociado a su respectivo documento (esto lo hago en una función que guarda los documentos y los detalles en un registro).

```
public static function guardarRegistro($paciente, $request)
{
    $request['patient_id'] = $paciente->id; 
    $request['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id; 
    
    $registro = Registry::create($request->all());

        if ($detalle !== null) 
        {
            $registro->documentos()->attach($documento, ['details' => $detalle]);

            $registro->save();
        }

        else {
            $registro->documentos()->attach($documento);

            $registro->save();
        }

    return $registro;
}
```

Agradezco su colaboración.

Comment: No se entiende... ¿El problema lo tienes con PHP/Laravel o con Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres descartar los campos ocultos desde PHP, tan solo debes hacer lo siguiente:
Debes hacer un bucle foreach del array que muestras en la segunda capura (la del array con nulls), y en ese foreach, compruebas si el valor es null y lo descartas con unset().

```
foreach ($array_datos as $i => $dato) { // Por cada elemento en el array
    if (is_null($dato) || strlen($dato) < 1) { // Si es NULL o no tiene carácteres
        unset($array_datos[$i]); // Quitar el elemento del array
    }
}
```

Puedes hacer lo mismo desde el lado del cliente, es decir, con JavaScript o TypeScript siguiendo la misma metodología.

Comment: amigo mio, te agradezco de todo corazón, muchisimas gracias!!!